# All Erase button (painting app with canvas)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I followed this tutorial to make a very basic paint app : http://www.williammalone.com/articles/create-html5-canvas-javascript-drawing-app/

I stopped at the first step (because it's all I wanted), except that I cannot erase like in the first example shown on the tutorial website. I suppose I made a mistake at linking the javascript function called "redraw" to the Erase button.

Here is my code :

```
   <head>
       <title>TEST PAINTING</title>
       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
       <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        $( document ).ready(function() {
        var canvasDiv = document.getElementById('canvasDiv');
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.setAttribute('width', "500");
        canvas.setAttribute('height', "200");
        canvas.setAttribute('id', 'canvas');
        canvasDiv.appendChild(canvas);
        if(typeof G_vmlCanvasManager != 'undefined') {
            canvas = G_vmlCanvasManager.initElement(canvas);
        }
        context = canvas.getContext("2d");

        //
        $('#canvas').mousedown(function(e){
            var mouseX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
            var mouseY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;

            paint = true;
            addClick(e.pageX - this.offsetLeft, e.pageY - this.offsetTop);
            redraw();
        });

        $('#canvas').mousemove(function(e){
            if(paint){
                addClick(e.pageX - this.offsetLeft, e.pageY - this.offsetTop, true);
                redraw();
            }
        });       

        $('#canvas').mouseup(function(e){
            paint = false;

        });

        $('#canvas').mouseleave(function(e){
            paint = false;
        });

        $('#clearCanvasSimple').click(function(e){
            clearCanvs();
        });

        var clickX = new Array();
        var clickY = new Array();
        var clickDrag = new Array();
        var paint;

        function addClick(x, y, dragging)
        {
            clickX.push(x);
            clickY.push(y);
            clickDrag.push(dragging);
        }

        function redraw()
        {
            context.clearRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height); // Clears the canvas

            context.strokeStyle = "#333";
            context.lineJoin = "round";
            context.lineWidth = 8;

            for(var i=0; i < clickX.length; i++) {        
                context.beginPath();
                if(clickDrag[i] && i){
                    context.moveTo(clickX[i-1], clickY[i-1]);
                }else{
                    context.moveTo(clickX[i]-1, clickY[i]);
                }
                context.lineTo(clickX[i], clickY[i]);
                context.closePath();
                context.stroke();
            }
        }

        function clearCanvas()
        {
            clickX = new Array();
            clickY = new Array();
            clickDrag = new Array();
            context.clearRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height); // Clears the canvas
        }

}); 
        </script>
   </head>
   <body>
        <div><button id="clearCanvasSimple" href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="clearCanvas()" type="button">Erase</button></div>
        <div class="cadre" id="canvasDiv"></div>        
   </body>
```

Does anyone know how I could make this "Erase" button work?

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've set the redraw button to just repaint the code again.

It should be doing something like this:

```
function clearCanvas()
{
    clickX = new Array();
    clickY = new Array();
    clickDrag = new Array();
    context.clearRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height); // Clears the canvas
});
```

We clear the current points, then clear the canvas.

Place the clearCanvas function after the redraw function and add the following jquery to register the click on the button (all in side the ready function).

```
$('#clearCanvasSimple').click(function(e){
    clearCanvas();
});
```

Comment: Actually, once you clear the points you could just call redraw() instead of the clearRect as "redraw" clears the canvas first.

Comment: I added the clearCanvas function and tried to call it this way but my button still doesn't work : <button id="clearCanvasSimple" href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="clearCanvas()" type="button">Erase</button> am I doing it wrong?

Comment: I think the scope may be wrong and it can't "find" the function. I'll update the solution.

Comment: I updated my first post with the new code. I'm sadly still not sure how to make it work.

Comment: Sorry, I spelt the function wrong, I've updated it now. Switch `clearCanvs();` to `clearCanvas();`  in your code (see this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PeXLT/1/ )